# How to Sort Everything in an Array Except Special Chars - Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, nlp-question-answering

I am trying to sort an array of letters alphabetically, but keep the special character in the same spot, in ruby.

For example,

`word = ["f", "a", "s", "t", "-", "c", "a", "r", "s"]`

How can I sort the whole thing alphabetically, but keep the "-" where it is. If I sort how it is now then the "-" will go to the front which I don't want. I have tried fifteen different ways, and I can't figure it out. Can you help?

Comment: What do you expect the transformed array to look like?

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs `"a", "a", "c", "f", "-", "r", "s", "s", "t"]`

Comment: Oh! just realized something! Maybe I can add it by its original index? Iterate through the first array, find the index of the special char, go through the second array and use the insert method at the index?

Comment: @anothernewbiecoder Yeah that will work. If you figure it out then post your answer (you are allowed to answer your own question).

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs Got it to work, I guess all I had to do was post it on here lol

Answer (score 1):

Some really verbose way to do this, to explain the logic around what you need to achieve. There's some 'cleaner' methods to achieve this, but I feel this gives more understanding.

Adding an additional special character to the array for better test coverage:

```
let(:input) { ["f", "a", "s", "t", "-", "c", "a", "r", "s", "/"] }
let(:desired_output) { ["a", "a", "c", "f", "-", "r", "s", "s", "t", "/"] }

it "takes the input and gives the desired output" do
  expect(sort_alphanumeric_characters(input)).to eq(desired_output)
end
```

Call `.map` and `.select` on the array to enumerate over the values and then call [`.with_index`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerator/with_index) as you'll need to retain indicies for later.

```
def sort_alphanumeric_characters(word_as_array)
  # assuming you mean non-alphanumeric
  # collect those indicies which are 'special' characters
  # the regex matches the string with anything outside of the alphanumeric range. Note the '^'
  special_character_indicies = word_as_array.map.with_index { |val, indx| indx if val =~ /[^a-zA-Z0-9]/ }.compact
  # collect all characters by index that were not yielded as 'special'
  alphanumeric_array = word_as_array.select.with_index { |char, indx| char unless special_character_indicies.include? indx }
  # sort the alphanumeric array
  sorted_alphanumeric_array = alphanumeric_array.sort
  # use Array#insert to place the 'special' by index
  special_character_indicies.each do |special_indx|
    special_char = word_as_array[special_indx]
    sorted_alphanumeric_array.insert(special_indx, special_char)
  end
  # return desired output
  sorted_alphanumeric_array
end
```

Comment: And what are methods that can do it? I thought of a lot, and I feel like I am right there but I can't see it. I was thinking insert would be really helpful!

Comment: It's all outlined above, no?

Comment: Oh, I thought you were saying there was something in addition to that!

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I posted I had a lightning bolt (love it when that happens). This is really not that great of a solution, but it did work!!

```
    def scramble_words(str)
      idx = 0 
      chars = str.delete("^a-z").chars
      first_ele = chars.shift
      last_ele = chars.pop
    
      str.chars.each_with_index {|c, i| idx = i if c =~ /[^a-z" "]/ }
    
      (first_ele + chars.sort.join  + last_ele).insert(idx, str[idx])
    
    end
    
    p scramble_words('card-carrying') == 'caac-dinrrryg'
    p scramble_words("shan't") == "sahn't"
    p scramble_words('-dcba') == '-dbca'
```

Comment: ```scramble_words 'this-HAS-more-THAN-one-SPECIAL-character-AND-capslocks-WORDS'
IndexError: index 59 out of string``` so you're removing a lot of characters with the regex and only really expecting one special character in that solution

Comment: The first and last character are treated differently. If this is the actual output you expect, you should update your question accordingly. (also include those examples in your question)

Comment: Oh yeah! I didn’t tell that part. The first and last letter stay in the same place and the special character. Then the middle scrambles.

Comment: The reason I didn’t add that part is because I knew that part. The part I was struggling with was keeping the special character there and sorting everything else. I showed the whole problem but I can change it?

Comment: @benjessop that is right! I didn't think of that at first, and then I ran into a test case that had multiple special characters and had a major facepalm moment. I ended switching this to a hash. So, I iterated over the string putting all special characters into a hash. Then at the end I inserted them.